# F# json parser does not recognize floats

Tags: json, f#, f#-data

I was trying json fsharp.data in a f# project.
But it seems the json parser does not recognise floats.

```
open FSharp.Data

type Simple = JsonProvider<""" 
  { "float": 1.0, "int":1, "string": "xxx" } 
  """>

let input = Simple.Parse(""" 
  { "float": 12.3, "int":234, "string": "string"  } 
  """)

printfn "%A %A %A" input.Float input.Int input.String
// the float seems to be read as an int
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your sample input for `"float": 1.0` property is *technically* an integer (in the numeric sense) even though you've put a decimal place in it.

> In general, the provider supports (and prefers them in this order): `int`, `int64`, `decimal` and `float`.

This will make `JsonProvider` infer `"float"` as `decimal` type:

```
type Simple = JsonProvider<"""
  { "float": 1.1, "int":1, "string": "xxx" }
  """>
```

This will make `JsonProvider` infer `"float"` as `float` type, because it's too large for `decimal`:

```
type Simple = JsonProvider<"""
  { "float": 1314814912414812342456456456456456456433333313148149124148123424564564564564564564333333.0, "int":1, "string": "xxx" }
  """>
```

Please see the [documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html) for more on how `JsonProvider` infers data types from JSON samples.

Comment: OK.
I now tried:
{
    type Simple = JsonProvider<"""
    {  "float": 1.0e30 , "decimal":1.1, int: 1,  "string": "xxx" }  """>

    let input = Simple.Parse(""" 
    { "float": 12.3, decimal: 2.34, "int":234, "string": "string"  }   """)
}

The float is correctly parsed  now.
But the  decimal is parsed as an int, and this is different from the documentation.

Comment: I see now,
In my test it was: "decimal": 1.0  this seems then to interpreted as an int.
I need to specify: "decimal": 1.1, then it's OK.